# VS -TFS bug_ Not show dropdown menu "View history" of solution in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Can someone help me with that bug in Visual studio with Team Foundation Server?

The dropdown menu "View history" didn't show in "Solution Explorer" (image below).

But sometimes, when I click at "Check in" to solution (then may either cancel or check in), then comeback to dropdown menu, it magically appear (sadly sometime it not).

So almost everytime, I must go to "Team Explorer" and navigate to "Source control Explorer" to View history of my solution. These actions take time, and make me frustrated too.

Thank you for any help, or alternative method!

P/S: I met it in all VS2013 and VS2015.

Image when menu is disappear (almost everytime):
[image: VS_error]

And appear after checking in all solution (rarely):

[image: yeah]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you able to see "View History" from File--Source Control? I couldn't see this issue with my TFS 2015.3 + VS 2015.3.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Our server admin say it's TFS 2010 (30319.01). But I think that's VS error or bug related to network or something... And of course, I can always see "View History" from File--Source Control. Do you have any suggest to fast navigate to "View History" of Solution?

Comment: No...You would either go to File--Source Control, or view history in Source Control Explorer. If you would be able to upgrade your TFS, the should go away.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm wrong in my previous comment. When it get bug I only see "View History" in "Source Control Explorer", not "File-Soure control-".

Comment: So you need to check history in Source Control Explorer, or use History Command to display the history: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see this issue with my TFS 2015.3 + VS 2015.3. You would have to check history in Source Control Explorer, or use History Command to display the history: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh(v=vs.100).aspx.

If possible, I'd like to suggest you upgrade your TFS, I couldn't see this issue in both TFS 2013 and TFS 2015.